# jcarousel - Customization

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jquery plugin 'jcarousel' - as i can't use it as is - i am trying to fit it to my requirements: 
my code:

```
function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{  
  for (var i = carousel.first; i < 10; i++) {
   if (carousel.has(i)) { continue;  }
   carousel.add(i, mycarousel_getItemHTML());
  }
  }     

function mycarousel_getItemHTML()
{ return '<a class="img" href="'+ itemURL + '"><img width="75px" height="100px" class="img" src="' + imgSrc + '" itemprop="image"></a>';}
```

-Constructing itemURL and imgSrc on a button click - right now - I am seeing the same image on 10 slots in carousal - I understood whats happening here - but in jcarousal documentation - for getting the li items dynamically they are getting it from a pre-filled list - in my case I wont have any list just gave it 10 for time being - i will have current item (any time only 1) - any ideas on how to fit it to my requirement - I want to add to carousel on button click